# How to check if user exists in Unit Test ? in Magento2

Tags: magento2, model, testing, unit-tests, object-manager

This my the code, and it's working normally, but in test unit, it is not working ? he said that he doesn't have the `create` method.

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $userModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\User\Model\User');
    $userModel->loadByUsername("bbbb");     
    $role_id_under_selected_user = $userModel->loadByUsername("bbbb")->getRoles();      
    if ($userModel->getData('password') == NULL || empty($role_id_under_selected_user)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried to use this $objectManager = new ObjectManager($this);  instead of  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); but it's didn't works too.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is ? Can I check if "bbbb" user is existed or not ? without objectManager... because objectManager is not working for me...

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not show the unit test code, I can only speculate, but it looks like you have an instance of the unit test object manager `\Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager` - it works differently and does not have a `create()` method. Instead it has (amongst others) a methods `getObject()` which gives you a new instance of the requested class with all dependencies mocked

**It's recommended to neither use the unit object manager nor the real object manager in unit tests!**<sup>1</sup>

Here's a statement from a Magento 2 core developer:

> When M2 development started all classes use Mage::* methods and we
>   start increase coverage with unit test. But when we add new
>   constructor injection many test start fails. So, we decide to
>   introduce helper class to avoid the unneeded work.
>
> But now constructor dependencies are stabilized, so helper is not need
>   in most cases

<sup>**Source:** https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140433/243</sup>

Instead, instantiate the object under test with `new` and instantiate or stub/mock all dependencies explicitly.

In the production code (i.e. not the test), you should not use the object manager either, but instead use dependency injection and factories. If your code needs to instantiate a new `User` object, add `\Magento\User\Api\Data\UserInterfaceFactory $userFactory` as constructor parameter, and then replace

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$userModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\User\Model\User');
```

with

```
$userModel = $this->userFactory->create();
```

If you update the question with test code and maybe some more context, I can give you an example for the test as well.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Integration tests are a different topic, there you should use the real object manager to test that your DI configuration works correctly.

---

### Update

From the question title, I guess you actually ***are*** writing an integration test, i.e. during the test your code operates on the database and you want to check if a user has been saved as expected.

In that case, the following works perfectly fine:

1. Get object manager from test framework bootstrap:

   ```
   $objectManager = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()
   ```
2. Get object manager directly:

   ```
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   ```

But your test should be executed as integration test, not as unit test. More on that here: [Creating Integration Tests for Magento 2 Modules](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93422/creating-integration-tests-for-magento-2-modules/104897#104897)

Comment: Thanks @Fabian Schmengler, It's still doesn't works for me :/, May you write me a simple and short code for it.. with the constructor and the setup function and the testFunction ... 20-40 line codes how much it's takes.. my code is very simple, and from the begining... I will be more than happy that you will help me and other which stuck with this problem...

Comment: class bbbTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase this is my class for example...

Comment: No, but if you update your question with a simple and short test code to reproduce your issue (minimum working example), I am willing to help fix it

Comment: I add code in the end... May you help me.. Thanks..